# Centering a text properly

Tags: spacing

I want to center a set with contains words as follows

```
{

x in A : x is suppose to be centered}.

I tried the following:  
$$\{x\in A : x is suppose to be centered}$$
```

which outputs {x in A : xissupposetobecentered}. All of the letters are smashed together, which is something I don't want. How can I fix this?

Comment: Please give us some clues, are you using plain Tex or context or latex?

Comment: `\usepackage{amsmath}
\[
\{x \in A : x \text{ is supposed to be centered} \}
\]`

Comment: You are not supposed to write words inside dollars. A sequence of chars is seen by tex as a product of single-char-named variables, and spaces are ignored. So $Hello$ is indeed the product of $H$, $o$, $l$, $l$, and $o$. This explains the awkward spacing. To write words inside a math environment use `\text{}` (from `amstext` package).

Comment: @JLDiaz perhaps better to directly recommend loading `amsmath` which internally loads `amstext` and offers other useful features?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Right. Unfortunately comments cannot be edited.

Comment: @JLDiaz Unfortunately, I have been using Latex only for the past 3 days or so. I am quite unfamiliar with most of its functions.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the \text command like this:

```
\[ \{x\in A : x \text{ is suppose to be centered} \} \]
```

Comment: Please, don't suggest `$$...$$` for LaTeX documents; use `\[...\]` instead. Also, braces need to be escaped: `\{` and `\}` and there's a space missing between the `x` and the text.

Comment: Thanks, changed it. Could you tell me the difference between $$ and \[ ?

Comment: `$$...$$` is a TeX command which might produce undesired results under certain circumstances in LaTeX. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/3954.

Comment: Welcome to the site.